# React native app has inverted colors on some phones

Tags: android, react-native, expo, background-color

I start alpha tests of my reat natvie app and one of the testers reported to me that on his phone the app is looking like in dark mode:

[image]
[image]

I am really surprised because my application **does not have any dark mode** functionality implemented and should look like this:

[image]
[image]

Tester is using **Xiaomi mi10 lite** phone.

Most of my app screens has on top `SafeAreaView` with style like that:

```
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: colors.secondaryColor,
  },
```

Where secondaryColor is `'#abf0d1'`, sometimes backgroundColor is white like on second screenshot.
Does anyone have any idea what this color-inverting thing could be caused by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because MIUI 12+ version has an advanced feature in Dark mode for Individual apps, This feature turns the Light theme app with no dark theme support to a Dark theme layout by inverting the layout colors.

If your app is only supporting Light theme you can prevent Force Dark mode by,

add a new property to your main `AppTheme` in `res/values/` resources `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item> // <-- add this 
  ...
```

Comment: Does anyone know a solution for this issue for Expo?

Comment: @Andropogon have you find a solution for Expo?

Comment: try `userInterfaceStyle` config -  https://docs.expo.dev/guides/color-schemes/#managed-projects